# SAS PROC GPLOT ERROR: The ORDER= entry is not a legend value

Tags: sas

My problem is with the order option of legend statement in Proc GPLOT in SAS.
I can't get my graph to show only selected variables in the legend.

I have tried changing the names of the variables and their labels, and I know a similar procedure was working perfectly fine on other data.

```
ods html file="..." gpath="...";                         
ods graphics on;                                                                                                                        

goptions reset=all hsize=24cm vsize=15cm;                                                                                               

Title;                                                                                                                                  
axis1 label = none                                                                                                                      
order = (300000 to 1000000 by 100000)                                                                                                   
value = (angle=0 height=1.5);                                                                                                           
axis2 label = none                                                                                                                      
/* order = (1 to 12 by 1) */                                                                                                            
offset = (0.4 cm, 0.4 cm)                                                                                                               
minor=none                                                                                                                              
value = (angle=0 height=1.5                                                                                                             
'sty' 'lut' 'mar' 'kwi' 'maj' 'cze' 'lip' 'sie' 'wrz' 'paź' 'lis' 'gru');                                                               


symbol1 color="Medium Vivid Red" interpol=spline line=1 value=dot height=1.2 width=1;                                                   
symbol2 color="Medium Vivid Blue" interpol=spline line=1 value=dot height=1.2 width=1;                                                  
symbol3 color="Medium Vivid Red" interpol=spline line=3 value=none height=1.2 width=1;                                                  
symbol4 color="Medium Vivid Blue" interpol=spline line=2 value=none height=1.2 width=1;                                                 
symbol5 color="Medium Vivid Red" interpol=spline line=3 value=none height=1.2 width=1;                                                  
symbol6 color="Medium Vivid Blue" interpol=spline line=2 value=none height=1.2 width=1;                                                 

legend1 order=('ExpPred' 'ArimaPred' 'ExpU95' 'ArimaU95') label=none value = (justify= left                                             
'F' 'S' 'T' 'G') frame;                                                                                                                 
/* legend1 order=('ExpPred' 'ArimaPred' 'ExpU95' 'ArimaU95') label=none shape=symbol(4,1.25) value = (justify= left                     
'Prognoza modelem Wintersa' 'Prognoza modelem SARIMA' 'Przedziały ufności (95%) - Model Wintersa'                                       
 'Przedziały ufności (95%) - Model SARIMA'); */                                                                                         

proc gplot data = ltz.ltz_Comp2019;                                                                                                  

plot (ExpPred ArimaPred ExpU95 ArimaU95 ExpL95 ArimaL95)*data                                                                                                                                                                                                                  / vaxis=axis1 haxis=axis2 legend=legend1 overlay;                                                                                       

run;                                                                                                                                    
quit;                                                                                                                                   

ods graphics off;                                                                                                                       
ods html close;
```

I expect to get a graph with only the values selected in the order statement in the legend, but I get the error:
ERROR: The ORDER= entry "ExpPred" is not a legend value.

The same error is given with other variables or if changed the name of the variable.

Added photo of dataset:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULfPp.png

Comment: Can you show some example code of where this method works?

Comment: For example, this code returns what it should:
https://pastebin.com/JNWSYQWe